# How do I make a Page Template that I created in the ZMI visible from the Plone Contents tab?

Tags: plone

I created a Page Template in the Custom folder using the ZMI.

I copied it using the ZMI into an existing Plone Folder.

I would like for this Page Template object to be visible in the Plone Contents tab. What must I do?

Answer (score 4):

If the template is not a view for other content (i.e., it stands on its own), then:

1) Create a folder (in Plone) to contain the template. This folder will show in navigation.

2) Put your template into the folder (using the ZMI) and change its short name (ID) to index_html. That forces it to be the default view.

3) Don't put anything else in the folder. At least not anything for which you need Plone's editing, navigation or view machinery.

OR, if you're allowing the link type to show in navigation, just put in a link type and point it to the template. Much safer than the index_html recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in Plone.

Add `/manage_propertiesForm` to the url and add a new property `layout` with as value the **id** of your template (which can remain in the custom folder).

Your template is now the default view of this folder.

Answer (score 0):

we have created new content type for this issue.